# What are some evidence-based techniques for speech therapy?

Tags: language-development

My son is just over three years old.  He has had glue ear, sometimes in both ears.

What are some evidence-based speech therapy techniques and games that can be applied by parents in the home?

Comment: You might find this blog generally helpful if you are not already aware of it: [Mommy Speech Therapy](http://mommyspeechtherapy.com/?page_id=50) She makes sure to suggest using the judgement and help of an actual speech therapist or pathologist but gives a lot of basic - get-you-started and keep you going kind of information parents can use on top of the therapy their kids are already doing with an expert.  She also offers free worksheets and the like.  I am not a regular reader of the blog, but it looks well done from a cursory look and she is a trained and experienced speech pathologist

Comment: I believe a child is entitled to special education services at no cost to you through your local school district from birth through age 22. Professional help is there for you!

Answer (score 1):

balanced mama has a great suggestion, but given that "glue ear" affects children based on a number of factors (e.g. duration and recurrence) and that how it affects is also highly variable, this question doesn't lead to the ability to answer or provide a suggestion specific to your child's needs or more abstractly to "any 'ole child who has had glue ear"'s needs.  In fact, given the high degree of variability, this question is best-suited for a professional's analysis of the total effect and how you ought to proceed forward and, I suggest, would require the monitoring of your professional over time to ensure treatment is appropriate at all levels of development.